# Checking if an XML node exists in an XML variable on SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an XML variable, `@XMLContent`, on SQLServer 2016, and I would like to find if node `<COLOR>` exists inside the root node `<PRODUCT>`.  Please note that `<PRODUCT>` might contain multiple `<COLOR>`.

```
DECLARE @XMLContent XML;
SET @XMLContent = '<PRODUCT><PRICE>9.99</PRICE><QUANTITY>28</QUANTITY><COLOR>BLUE</COLOR><COLOR>RED</COLOR></PRODUCT>'
```

The condition should return TRUE for the `@XMLContent` above and

```
SET @XMLContent = '<PRODUCT><PRICE>34.99</PRICE><QUANTITY>7</QUANTITY></PRODUCT>'
```

Should return FALSE

What would be the most efficient way to write that condition? Can I use `.exist` for this specific scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , using .exists you can even check the value  tag in the XML , for example

```
DECLARE @XMLContent XML;
SET @XMLContent = '<PRODUCT><PRICE>9.99</PRICE><QUANTITY>28</QUANTITY><COLOR>BLUE</COLOR><COLOR>RED</COLOR></PRODUCT>'
IF (@XMLContent.exist('/PRODUCT[COLOR="RED"]')=1)
BEGIN
  SET @XMLContent = '<PRODUCT><PRICE>34.99</PRICE><QUANTITY>7</QUANTITY></PRODUCT>' 
END
```